# How to create a solution only from .aspx and .aspx.cs files in asp.net/c#

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have got .aspx and .aspx.cs files along with a web.config file; from these files I want to create a solution in order to run them as an ASP.NET website.

To be more precise, I downloaded the code snippet available on [this site](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Preserving-state-of-Checkboxes-while-paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control.aspx) but could not get it to run.

How can I create a project/solution from these files which I can run locally?

Comment: What happened? What errors did you get? "i could not run" is a poor problem description.

Comment: @oded i just could not run the program because there is no solution for the files. Any ways as Maxim suggested opening the folder as asp.net website worked but now there seems to be a new problem as there is no northwind database included in the project. It could not find the database. Any suggestions !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just open it as a *Web site*:
File -> Open -> Web Site... -> File system -> [Select the folder where you put those files]

Explanation: in terms of Visual Studio, *Web Sites* are folder-based projects (that is, there is no project file).

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked. Although I could not run the program because it required northwind database which i don't have. If possible can u take a look at the files available at the link specified in my question

Comment: Northwind DB is a sample database used by Microsoft for demonstration purposes. You can get it **[there](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=06616212-0356-46a0-8da2-eebc53a68034&displaylang=en)**. If you need further assistance on this topic, you'd better ask a new question, to keep topics separated.